# Comparing elements from 2 list kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

im having 2 list of different variable, so i want to compare and update the 'Check' value from list 2 if the 'Brand' from list 2 is found in list 1

```
--------------------    --------------------    
| Name   | Brand   |    | Brand    | Check |
--------------------    -------------------- 
| vga x  | Asus    |    | MSI      |   X   |
| vga b  | Asus    |    | ASUS     |   -   |
| mobo x | MSI     |    | KINGSTON |   -   |
| memory | Kingston|    | SAMSUNG  |   -   | 
--------------------    --------------------
```

so usually i just did

```
for(x in list1){
  for(y in list2){
     if(y.brand == x.brand){
        y.check == true
     }
  }
}
```

is there any simple solution for that?

Comment: Why `y.check == true` ? It's not better `y.check = true`. And you can write a little shorter with Ternary Operator

Answer (score 1):

Since you're mutating the objects, it doesn't really get any cleaner than what you have. It can be done using `any` like this, but in my opinion is not any clearer to read:

```
    list2.forEach { bar ->
        bar.check = bar.check || list1.any { it.brand == bar.brand }
    }
```

The above is slightly more efficient than what you have since it inverts the iteration of the two lists so you don't have to check every element of `list1` unless it's necessary. The same could be done with yours like this:

```
    for(x in list2){
        for(y in list1){
            if(y.brand == x.brand){
                x.check = true
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data class Item(val name: String, val brand: String)

fun main() {
    val list1 = listOf(
        Item("vga_x", "Asus"),
        Item("vga_b", "Asus"),
        Item("mobo_x", "MSI"),
        Item("memory", "Kingston")
    )
    
     val list2 = listOf(
        Item("", "MSI"),
        Item("", "ASUS"),
        Item("", "KINGSTON"),
        Item("", "SAMSUNG")
    )
    
    // Get intersections
    val intersections = list1.map{it.brand}.intersect(list2.map{it.brand})
    println(intersections)
    
    // Returns => [MSI]
    
    // Has any intersections
    val intersected = list1.map{it.brand}.any { it in list2.map{it.brand} }
    println(intersected)
    
    // Returns ==> true
    
}
```

**UPDATE:** I just see that this isn't a solution for your problem. But I'll leave it here.